# Как открыть порт 22 на mac os?

Tags: ssh, mac

Хочу подключиться по ssh к своему макбуку, но пишет, что `connection refused`. Видимо порт закрыт. Но с макбука подключиться, допустим, к убунте я могу. Как открыть 22 порт?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, что ваш порт, вероятно, открыт, но у вас нет ничего, что бы слушало его.

> В операционной системе Apple Mac OS X по умолчанию установлен SSH, но
>   демон SSH не включен. Это означает, что вы не можете войти в систему
>   удаленно или сделать удаленные копии, пока не включите его.
>
> Чтобы включить его, перейдите в «Системные настройки». В разделе
>   «Интернет и сети» есть значок «Совместное использование». Запустите
>   это. В появившемся списке установите флажок «Удаленный вход». В OS X
>   Yosemite и выше уже нет меню «Интернет и сеть»; Он был перенесен на
>   учетные записи. В меню «Общий доступ» теперь есть собственный значок в
>   главном меню «Системные настройки».
>
> Это немедленно запускает демон SSH, и вы можете удаленно входить в
>   систему, используя свое имя пользователя. Окно «Совместное
>   использование» показывает внизу имя и IP-адрес для использования. Вы
>   также можете найти это, используя «whoami» и «ifconfig» из приложения
>   Terminal.

Эти инструкции взяты из [Enable SSH в Mac OS X](http://www.bluishcoder.co.nz/articles/mac-ssh.html), но я хотел убедиться, что они не исчезнут и предоставят быстрый доступ.

Перевод ответа https://stackoverflow.com/a/6313937/7847084

Comment: Я пытался, нет там таких кнопок. Тут изменено, в ответе, но там несколько параметров, я попробую, конечно и отвечу

Comment: У вас какой OSX ?

Comment: Да, все работает, спасибо:)